# Android: obtain ImageView's src from code

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` whose resource ID should be calculated based on some logic in the view model. So, I'd like to do something like this:

```
<ImageView android:src="@{viewModel.icon}" />
```

```
@Bindable
public int getIcon() {
    switch (foo) {
    case BAR:
        return R.drawable.bar;
        ...
    }
}
```

However, this code does not work. `android:src` is expecting a `Drawable` instead of an `int`. I am aware of `setImageResource()` but I don't want to use it. I want to stick to the principle that "the view is a function of the view model", i.e. no side effects.

I have tried `context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId)` and it worked. But it's a little clumsy since I need to keep a `context` around, either in the view model or as a global/static reference, although it looks like it's still within the realm of the model view paradigm.

Is anyone aware of an elegant solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get solve your problem.

```
object BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    fun setSrcCompat(imageView: ImageView, resId: Int) {
        imageView.setImageResource(resId)
    }
}
```

[Binding Adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)

Comment: Thanks! It's not as concise I'd hoped. I'd need to add this function to every view model. But it doesn't require holding onto a context. So that's a win.

Comment: Is it necessary to include it in every ViewModel? You actually just need to define it once. Edited check please.